# Terminal can't show the colors properly

Tags: terminal, manjaro, gnome-terminal

I'm using doom Emacs and today for the first time I started a terminal inside Emacs and I saw colors are showing so much better than my default terminal. same background, same font, but the colors on Emacs are so much better.

[image: Terminal colors]

I'm using the default terminal of Manjaro with gnome desktop.

My terminal exact version:

> GNOME Terminal
>
> 3.34.2
>
> A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop
> Using VTE version 0.58.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS

*Sorry for bad English*

### Edit:

In my terminal `echo $TERM` show me this output: `xterm-256color` but in Emacs it's equal to: `eterm-color` but `eterm-color` is not supported in my terminal, can I some how add it?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs is capable of sending escape sequences to change the color palette, and restoring the palette.  If it is paying attention to the `xterm-256color` terminal entry, it can (still) choose different colors within that palette which are not necessarily available to the GNU `ls` program since that depends on the configuration used for `LS_COLORS`.

The [`eterm-color`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-eterm-color) terminal description is supplied by ncurses, and is used for **Emacs'** ansi-term terminal emulation (not related to gnome-terminal in any way).  Manjaro is apparently derived from Arch, which has this terminal description, so your extra question appears to be based on some notion that it ought to be the same as xterm-256color.  On the other hand, if someone trimmed the Arch package down for Manjaro, it could be missing (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91977/whats-the-right-value-of-term-for-emacs-ansi-term-especially-if-eterm-color/312151#312151) for discussion).